# How to resolve a verified property not appearing in the security issues property dropdown?

Tags: google-search-console, security, phishing

I have several verified properties across Google Search Console / Google Analytics.

Unfortunately, I've recently taken on a client that has been red flagged by Google as a Phishing site (which they are not). To get Google to lift the phishing warning the following page should be used apparently: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/security-issues

However, when I go to that page, this particular property is not visible. I click the add property button, and the property *is* there (meaning I can't add it).

Is there another way to submit the property to lift the phishing warning? Or to make it appear in the above link?

Answer (score 1):

The property was a domain property. The security tools don't work for domain properties, switched it over to a url property and all worked as intended